# Convert "#BAL#" into "#225#" using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string like this:

```
string ussdCommand = "#BAL#";
```

I'd like to convert that into "#225#".  At the moment, I have a dictionary defined like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("ABC", 2);
dictionary.Add("DEF", 3);
dictionary.Add("GHI", 4);
dictionary.Add("JKL", 5);
dictionary.Add("MNO", 6);
dictionary.Add("PQRS", 7);
dictionary.Add("TUV", 8);
dictionary.Add("WXYZ", 9);
```

And then I have a function that accepts my original string ("#BAL#") and converts it like this:

```
private static string ConvertLettersToPhoneNumbers(string letters)
{
    string numbers = string.Empty;
    foreach (char c in letters)
    {
        numbers += dictionary.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key.Contains(c)).Value.ToString();
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

As you'll notice right away, the problem is that my dictionary doesn't contain an entry for "#" so .FirstOrDefault() returns the default value and what I get back is "02250" instead of "#225#".  I don't have a dictionary entry for the # sign since it doesn't correspond to a number but is there a way to modify or override the default return value in .FirstOrDefault() so that it simply returns the # sign anytime it occurs in my input string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change it to use a `Dictionary<char, char>`, and use `TryGetValue` to easily find out whether or not there's a mapping:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<char, char> PhoneMapping =
    new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    { 'A', '2' }, { 'B', '2' }, { 'C', '2' },
    { 'D', '3' }, { 'E', '3' }, { 'F', '3' },
    { 'G', '4' }, { 'H', '4' }, { 'I', '4' },
    { 'J', '5' }, { 'K', '5' }, { 'L', '5' }, 
    { 'M', '6' }, { 'N', '6' }, { 'O', '6' },
    { 'P', '7' }, { 'Q', '7' }, { 'R', '7' }, { 'S', '7' },
    { 'T', '8' }, { 'U', '8' }, { 'V', '8' },
    { 'W', '9' }, { 'X', '9' }, { 'Y', '9' }, { 'Z', '9' }
};

private static string ConvertLettersToPhoneNumbers(string letters)
{
    char[] replaced = new char[letters.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < replaced.Length; i++)
    {
        char replacement;
        replaced[i] = PhoneMapping.TryGetValue(letters[i], out replacement)
            ? replacement : letters[i];
    }
    return new string(replaced);
}
```

Note that for *other* situations where you want a "first, but with a default" you can use:

```
var foo = sequence.DefaultIfEmpty(someDefaultValue).First();
```

Comment: Thank you for the .DefaultIfEmpty() explanation, too.

Answer (score 0):

Its working

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dictionary.Add("ABC", 2);
        dictionary.Add("DEF", 3);
        dictionary.Add("GHI", 4);
        dictionary.Add("JKL", 5);
        dictionary.Add("MNO", 6);
        dictionary.Add("PQRS", 7);
        dictionary.Add("TUV", 8);
        dictionary.Add("WXYZ", 9);


        string value = "BAL";
        string nummber = "#";
        foreach (char c in value)
        {

            nummber += dictionary.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key.Contains(c)).Value.ToString();
        }
        nummber += "#";

    }
```